# Color code points on 3D scatter plot with 350 points

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am doing PCA, that has 350 points to plot. I have successfully plotted them on a 3D plot. I want to color them to tell which point is which on my 3D plot. Is it possible to color each one? Maybe color points 1 to 50 different shades of green, then 51 to 100 different shades of red, etc? And the lighter the shade of color the smaller the number is?

Comment: That's definitively possible. I don't know the exact code, but what you have to (probably) do is: define an array with all the colors you want. `seaborn` has tools for defining color scales, so you can get a 50 color scale for green, red and blue and then append them. Then you have to sort your scatterdots and then loop through them so you give one of those colors to each in the order you want. If I had more time I could help you with the exact methods and functions, but now I can't. Hope it helps a bit

Comment: What plotting library?

Comment: Thank you Juan C. I will see what I can do with seaborn.

Comment: Linuxios - I am new to python so I think that the correct answer to your question is matplotlib. I am using ax.scatter to create a scatter plot.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear my suggestion was to plot on `matplotlib` but use `seaborn` tools for the color palettes

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned you have been trying to do this with `matplotlib` and `ax.scatter`. I think for your example all the functionality you need is already built into `ax.scater`, with the `c` input argument. For example, does the following meet your requirements?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some dummy data
xval = np.random.randn(350)
yval = np.random.randn(350)
zval = np.exp( - (xval**2 + yval**2)/0.5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

cax = ax.scatter(xval, yval, zval, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, c=zval) 
fig.colorbar(cax)
```

[image]